# VBA variable/array default values

Tags: arrays, vba, default-value

Consider the declarations

```
Dim x As Double
Dim avg(1 To 10) As Double
```

What are the default values in `x` and `avg`?

Through testing, I want to say that `x` is initialized to zero.
Likewise, I want to say that all elements in `avg` were initialized to zero.

However, can I write code that depends on this? Or are the default initialization values actually indeterminate?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you specify a data type but do not specify an initializer, Visual Basic initializes the variable to the default value for its data type, which for all numeric types is 0 (zero).

> When you run a macro, all the variables are initialized to a value. A
> numeric variable is initialized to zero, a variable length string is
> initialized to a zero-length string (""), and a fixed length string is
> filled with the ASCII code 0. Variant variables are initialized to
> Empty. An Empty variable is represented by a zero in a numeric context
> and a zero-length string ("") in a string context.

<s>[Ref](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/843144).</s> Link dead.

Instead: [How to use variables in Excel sub-procedures in Visual Basic for Applications](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/how-to-use-variables-in-excel-sub-procedures-in-visual-basic-for-applications-6da0960f-0bdc-460b-aebb-afc64deacc6b)

Comment: Pretty sure this is correct.  Note, however, that if you use dynamic arrays no elements are initialized and referencing arr(0) before explicitly setting it returns an error.

Comment: An aside, I'm pretty sure (by searching SO) that it isn't possible to specify an initializer at declaration in Excel VBA, since that's a .NET thing.
Thank you for the Ref! That totally dispels any doubt that `x` holds zero. Though is it the case that every element in a fixed array is also initialized to zero? I actually had already discovered that dynamic arrays don't get initialized (only allocated) upon declaration, and I just wanted to make sure fixed arrays declaration didn't behave the same way.

Comment: @Prashant, why not add a watch to the variable and test for yourself?

Answer (score 4):

You *can* write code that implicitly depends on a given data type's default value, but that doesn't mean you always *should*, because it isn't quite as obvious what you're doing, which may confuse the next person reading your code (and that person could be you a year from now).

You can't go wrong with explicitly assigning an initial value to your variables. If you want, you can do that on the same line as the declaration:

```
Dim x As Double: x = 0
```

Of course, it's a little more involved for arrays, but usually there's a convenient place to initialize them further down in your code, where you're traversing them anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be able to depend on number types being initialize to 0 in VBA since that's their default value.

However, if it makes you worry, and the starting values are so important, then my reccomendation is that you just explicitly assign the value 0 to them (although you really don't need to).