# Populate one dimensional array without looping

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

The following line of code will allocate an array as one dimensional `sortedArr = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(lstIssues1.List)`. This line of code allocates an array as two dimensional `arrIssues = Table.ListColumns(Table.ListColumns(strNumber).Range.column).DataBodyRange`

For each of the above lines I call a bubble sort function. But it errors on one or the other depending on whether I put

```
If Arr(i) > Arr(j) Then ...
```

Or

```
If Arr(i, 1) > Arr(j, 1) Then ...
```

I can loop to fill `arrIssues`. But I am wondering if it's possible to fill it as a one dimensional array without looping.

**UPDATE**

Here is the code I am having trouble with

```
Private Sub cmdRemove_Click()
Dim SortedArr() As Variant
    With lstPrevious
        If .ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub
        For i = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If .Selected(i) = True Then
                lstAdditional.AddItem .List(i)
                .RemoveItem (i)
            End If
        Next i
    End With
ReDim SortedArr(lstAdditional.ListCount - 1)
    SortedArr = Application.Transpose(lstAdditional.List) 'ERROR Type Mismatch
    Call BubbleSort(SortedArr)
    Me.lstAdditional.List = SortedArr
    txtFocus.SetFocus
End Sub

Public Sub BubbleSort(Arr)
Dim strTemp As String
Dim lngMin As Long
Dim lngMax As Long
    lngMin = LBound(Arr)
    lngMax = UBound(Arr)
    For i = lngMin To lngMax
        For j = i + 1 To lngMax
            If Arr(i) > Arr(j) Then
                strTemp = Arr(i)
                Arr(i) = Arr(j)
                Arr(j) = strTemp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Strangely, I use the same logic in another userform and it works. Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for?

[VBA (Excel) Initialize Entire Array without Looping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19336987/vba-excel-initialize-entire-array-without-looping)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to enter different values from a range. Just wanting to do it without loops. But I may end up looping.

Comment: Loops aren't a bad thing ;-)

Comment: Two possible solutions, if I understand you correctly.  `1`: Transpose the 2D array (if the array is not greater than the upper limit for Transpose, which varys depending on your version of Excel).  Or `2`: Check to see how many dimensions are in your array, and then apply the appropriate sort formula.

Comment: What do people have against looping all of a sudden?  Does typing `For foo = 1 to bar` really take longer than writing a question on SO?

Comment: Try this: remove the parentheses from `Dim SortedArr As Variant`, and remove the `Redim` statement.

Comment: @trincot Thanks for the suggestion but I still got the `Type Mismatch` error.

Answer (score 0):

> For each of the above lines I call a bubble sort function. But it errors on one or the other depending on whether I put If Arr(i) > Arr(j) Then ... Or If Arr(i, 1) > Arr(j, 1) Then ...

Your values of `i`, `j` are incorrect and hence it errors out. I am guessing that you are getting `Subscript out of range error`.

Here is a simple way to reproduce the error that you are getting.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Integer
    Dim MyAr As Variant

    MyAr = Range("A1:A5").Value

    For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
        For j = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
            If MyAr(j, 1) > MyAr(j + 1, 1) Then
                k = MyAr(j, 1)
                MyAr(j, 1) = MyAr(j + 1, 1)
                MyAr(j + 1, 1) = k
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

The correct way is to loop till `UBound(MyAr) - 1`

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Integer
    Dim MyAr As Variant

    MyAr = Range("A1:A5").Value

    For i = LBound(MyAr) To (UBound(MyAr) - 1)
        For j = LBound(MyAr) To (UBound(MyAr) - 1)
            If MyAr(j, 1) > MyAr(j + 1, 1) Then
                k = MyAr(j, 1)
                MyAr(j, 1) = MyAr(j + 1, 1)
                MyAr(j + 1, 1) = k
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added an update to my question.

Comment: Your edit doesn't make sense.. where are you using `If Arr(i) > Arr(j) Then ...` or `If Arr(i, 1) > Arr(j, 1) Then ...` My answer is based on that

Comment: I am using it in a separate module in a subroutine called `BubbleSort`. I am trying to put the contents of a listbox into an array and then pass the array to the `BubbleSort` subroutine. I added the sort routine above.

Comment: Change `lngMin = LBound(Arr)` to `lngMin = LBound(Arr) - 1` and similarly `lngMax = UBound(Arr)-1`